# Updating variable syntax in oracle

Tags: oracle, replace, regexp-replace

We have a table called `TEMPLATES` that stores html email templates as plain text. There are a number of columns in this table but the one we care is the `TEMPLATE` column which is where the text is stored.

We recently updated the libraries used by the server to parse these templates before they get sent to the user. These libraries use a new syntax for variables

```
${varName}
```

My problem is a lot of the old email templates use the old syntax

```
@varName@
```

These variable names contain only alpha-numeric characters. I'm trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE to replace all instances of a variable with the old `@whateverVariable@` syntax with the new `${whateverVariable}` syntax but I'm having difficulty preserving the variable name when I do the replacement. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do this?

I should probably mention the column is a CLOB if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLOB makes a difference in that REGEXP_REPLACE will truncate the template to 32k characters - are your templates longer than that?

Anyway, here's one way to do it. Note that it will NOT work without modification if in fact your variable names may contain non-alphanumeric characters (such as hyphen).

```
with
     inputs ( email_tmpl ) as (
       select 'Dear @mrmrs@ @fname@, ...whatever' from dual
     )
select regexp_replace(email_tmpl, '@([[:alnum:]]+)@', '${\1}') as new_tmpl
from   inputs
;


NEW_TMPL
-----------------------------------
Dear ${mrmrs} ${fname}, ...whatever

1 row selected.
```

Comment: @LeeAbraham -  In your post you said you had difficulty preserving the variable name. This is what the backreference `\1` does. It must refer back to a SUBEXPRESSION - a portion of the match pattern enclosed in parentheses. Perhaps you didn't have it enclosed in parentheses? Or maybe you had the + (for one or more characters) outside the parentheses instead of inside?